# Позиционирование блока относительно ширины элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, позиционирование

Приветсвую.
Демонстрация работы: https://codepen.io/Woody19/pen/dJwpXJ

Имеется следующее построение checkbox-ов на сайте:

```
<li>
<label class="cb-input">
    <input class="cb-input__checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <span class="cb-input__check"></span>
    <span class="cb-input__label">Calipso</span>
</label>
<label class="found-items"></label>
```

CSS лэйбла found-items:

```
.filter-menu li:hover .found-items {
display: block;
position: absolute;}

.filter-menu .found-items::before {
    content: "Найдено 230";
    position: absolute;
    left: 104px;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 5px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(62, 119, 199);
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 3px inset;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(62, 119, 199);
    border-image: initial;
}
.filter-menu .found-items:after {
content: '';
height: 13px;
width: 13px;
top: -21px;
left: 89px;
z-index: 1;
display: block;
background: white;
border: 3px solid #3e77c7;
border-right-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
transform-origin: 100% 0;
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg)!important;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg)!important;
transform: rotate(-45deg)!important;
position: absolute;}
```

При наведении на элемент списка должен появляться  где отображено количество найденных товаров, проблема в том что спаны с текстом имеют разную ширину (в зависимости от количества символов).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: как можно сделать при помощи Jquery/Vanila чтобы данный элемент выводился относительно ширины Calipso спана с текстом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.filter-menu li:hover .found-items {
    right: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, все отлично работает